# Question on practically using the Akaike information criterion

Tags: aic

I am trying to develop the correct intuition about practically using the cost function AIC.

I am under the impression that so long as the result of including an additional variable/parameter is a reduction in the variance of the error of more than 2, then the model should include the additional variable/parameter.

However, I don't quite understand how to interpret this in the case of an AIC Plot (number of parameters as the x-axis, AIC Value as the y-axis) that is, for example, similar to the positive section of $ (1/x) $ but with an increasing tail as x increases. In other words, the AIC function steeply decreases, hits a minimum value (suppose it is zero), then gradually ascends.

Does such an AIC plot suggest that you choose the minimum value? Or do you choose the value previous to the first value where the AIC value is less than 2 and ignore the rest of the plot?

I would guess that you choose the value previous to the first value that has an AIC value less than 2, otherwise you are sacrificing less bias for in-sample goodness of fit.

Comment: I wouldn't put too much into the analysis of AIC. If it's lower, then the model specification is better in this criterion.

Comment: @Aksakal Is that to say that choosing the number of parameters that minimizes the AIC value is the correct procedure?

Comment: People do use AIC to select model specifications, which include the parameter set (not just the number of params but the set of them). You may have different specifications with the same number of parameters. You have to be careful when comparing AIC of integrated and not-integrated models, e.g. I(1) vs. AR(1)

Comment: The correct procedure for modelling is to select the reparameterizations that best characterize the data. AIC has no role in this. Also, AIC cannot compare regression method A to regression method B even for the same model. It frequently occurs that the reciprocal of the x or y data, or their logarithm is more normally distributed than the original data set. So if all one is doing is using AIC for model selection, then the modelling chosen is likely to be inappropriate.  Just eyeballed the residual structure to determine how to represent the data works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally correct approach is to select the minimum value as shown by the AIC, not to consider the difference between each step (increase in parameters).